# Is the character deck common or individual?

Tags: teamfight-tactics

In teamfight tactics you choose from a selection of 5 characters shown at the bottom of the screen. When these characters are refreshed do they come from a deck that all players take cards from? Or do they come from a seperate deck just for you?

For example if I am trying to get 9 Nidalee cards, and someone else is also trying to get her as well, is the probability that her card comes up lower for me if they already have 5 of them?

Answer (score 2):

It is all explained here: https://www.invenglobal.com/articles/8481/tft-champion-pool-sizes-and-probabilities-revealed

But yes your theory is correct regarding Nidalee, if two or more people are trying to get her there is a much lower chance that you will finish a level 3 due to it being a shared pool.

Comment: Theres a big but here that everybody seems think it is, but I never seen confirmation that it's working like this. People seem to think that there is a prerolled bunch of champions (like there is 5 nidalees, 3 evelyns, etc) so taking a nidalee removes one for everybody else. What I think is how it works is that its a pool of 10 5 gold units, but it's not decided beforehand how much there is of every champion. It's at the moment it rolls it into your shop that it rolls a random 5 gold unit. Taking one Kayle takes the pool of 10 to 9, but not a pool of 5 kayles to 4.

Comment: Also, I've seen this morning that a 2 star unit counts as 1 towards the pool. So when you upgrade, you put back 2 units into the pool.

Comment: I am quite certain that upgrading/being knocked out/selling champions does NOT put them back into the pool.

Comment: So if you get a 3star Tier 5 unit you've got 90% of all Tier 5 units while trying to find a unit in particular? I find that hard to believe. But I've got no concrete proof, I just heard about it.